# kvmtool: guest OS fails: mounting /dev/vda on /root failed: No such device

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-16.04, paravirtualization

I am trying to load a guest Ubuntu using kvmtool. For this I am running following command.

`sudo ./lkvm run --disk ~/Downloads/ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img --kernel ~/kvmtool/guest_linux_kernel/linux-4.13/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage --network virtio -c 2 -m 6000 -i ~/kvmtool/guest_linux_kernel/linux-4.13/initrd-4.13.0-41-generic.img --name ubuntu`

This ends with "mounting /dev/vda on /root failed: No such device". Here is the output 
https://gist.github.com/proywm/6b67c689b22089664e00861bde158e9f

What is going on and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, your root device is configured as /dev/vda, but the image file you are providing has 3 partitions.  Did you try cloning a physical machine's disk?  You might want to try adding `-p root=/dev/vda1` or splitting the img into 3 disk images.

Comment: Adding `-p root=/dev/vda1` worked. Thanks.